# Cannot pass array to stored procedure in oracle

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I am getting following error when I pass array to stored procedure.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection
>   cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection

I am using Spring MVC with oracle 10g on Weblogic 11g server. I do a JNDI look up to connect to database. I also unchecked the Wrap data types check box in my Data sources configuration on weblogic server and restarted server. But still same error.

I am using ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar

Following is the like of code where I get the error

```
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor =  
    ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("Frc.Typ_Frc_Varray", 
        (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)  dataSource.getConnection());
```

I have data source autowired as follows

```
       @Autowired  
       DataSource dataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do your casting like this:

```
(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)  ((WLConnection)dataSource.getConnection()).getVendorConnection()
```

Comment: My dataSource.getConnection() does not have method getVendorConnection();

Comment: I tried this already. Same error. Please help as its blocking my work.

Comment: basically I am not able to get an OracleConnection. My connection type is Logicalconnection since its from a connection pool. Will PoolConnection help me?